# PHPでデータベースに接続するときにエラーが出る

Tags: php, html

エラーでコードがそのまま出ます

html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>フォーム画面</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>フォーム画面</h1> 
 
<form action="pdo_insert.php" method="post">
名前を入力：<input type="text" name="yourname">
<input type="submit" value="登録する">
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if(empty($_POST)) {
    header("Location: pdo_form.html");
    exit();
}else{
    //名前入力判定
    if (!isset($_POST['yourname'])  || $_POST['yourname'] === "" ){
        $errors['name'] = "名前が入力されていません。";
    }
}

if(count($errors) === 0){
    
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test5;charset=utf8';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'root';
    
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO name (name) VALUES (:name)");
        
        if($statement){
            $yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
            //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
            $statement->bindValue(':name', $yourname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            if(!$statement->execute()){
                $errors['error'] = "登録失敗しました。";
            }
            
            //データベース接続切断
            $dbh = null; 
        }
        
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        $errors['error'] = "データベース接続失敗しました。";
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>登録画面</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <?php if (count($errors) === 0): ?>
        <p><?=htmlspecialchars($yourname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."さんで登録いたしました。"?></p>
        <?php elseif(count($errors) > 0): ?>
        <?php
        foreach($errors as $value){
            echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
        }
        ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**手順**

1. XAMPPを起動 (→ 青いマークに)
2. ブラウザにhtmlファイルをドラッグ
3. フォームに入力、エンター
4. コードがそのまま表示される

Comment: PHP言語界隈ではエラーがでているというと、PHP言語が発生させている[エラー](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.errors.php)を指しますが、今回はそういうことではなくてPHPのソースコードがそのまま表示されている状態をご自身が「エラー」といっているということでよろしいですか？

Comment: はい そういうことです

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、より内容が伝わるようにタイトルや本文を書き換えてみてください。 / PHP がテキストとして表示されてしまうということであれば、まず PHP の実行環境が整っているのかを確認する必要があると思います。

Comment: OSXでXAMPPを起動してあります

Comment: となるとXamppのインストールや設定の手順にミスがあった可能性があります。インストールの手順とどのように設定をしたかを追記してください。

Comment: ちなみにDBに接続するときにエラーが出るといいますが、ほかのPHPコードはうまく実行できますか？

Comment: (回答は付いていませんが) ほぼ同じ内容の類似質問: [ブラウザにPHPのコードがそのまま表示されてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70201)

Comment: 例えば、PHP を動かすために行った手順を一つ一つ箇条書きにしてみると、何かが足りないとか間違っている、等の指摘もしやくすなると思います。

Comment: きちんとツールの公式のドキュメントを読んでおいたほうがいいと思います。英語ですが、[公式](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html)日本語でも記事があるので検索してみてください。基本として新しいツールを入れたら説明書は読みましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純な HTML であればブラウザへのドラッグ＆ドロップでも内容が表示されますが、PHP などを **プログラムとして動作させる** には Webサーバ (Apache) を通してアクセスする必要があります。

具体的には、Apache のドキュメントルートに HTML や PHP を保存し、ブラウザには `http://localhost/` 経由でアクセスしてみてください。

```
<XAMPPのインストール先>/htdocs/     ## <- このディレクリ以下に HTML や PHP を保存
```

例えば、`htdocs/form.html` として保存したなら `http://localhost/form.html` になります。

Comment: ちなみにここでいうXAMPPはアプリケーションでいいのですか？

Comment: また レンタルサーバー等を通して公開する場合 html css JavaScriptとともにアップすればいいのですか？ はなしをきいているとちがうようにおもえます