# HTMLでPHPのコードがそのまま表示される

Tags: php, macos, xampp

HTMLでPHPのコードがそのまま表示されるのはなぜでしょう？

```
<?php
 
//データベース接続
$server = "localhost";  
$userName = "root"; 
$password = "root"; 
$dbName = "sample01";
 
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $userName, $password,$dbName);
 
if ($mysqli->connect_error){
    echo $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}else{
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");
}
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name";
 
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
 
//クエリー失敗
if(!$result) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    exit();
}
 
//レコード件数
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
 
//連想配列で取得
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
 
//結果セットを解放
$result->free();
 
// データベース切断
$mysqli->close();
 
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>nameテーブル表示</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>nameテーブル表示</h1> 
 
レコード件数：<?php echo $row_count; ?>
 
<table border='1'>
<tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>
 
<?php 
foreach($rows as $row){
?> 
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
</tr> 
<?php 
} 
?>
 
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーメッセージ等はありません

図のようにPHPのコードがそのまま表示される だけです

環境は Mac XAMPP です

phpのファイルはRootに置いてあります

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エンターを押すと上記の図のように表示されます

アクセスしているURLは

file:///Volumes/root/4%20HTML%20/17%20/select.php

htmlファイルはhtdocsですが XAMPPの直下がわからない 置けないのでRootです

追記

htdocsに任意のファイルを置いてurlの最後尾を任意のファイル名に変えても表示されません

Comment: 落ち着いてご自分の質問を見直してみてください。途中のエラーメッセージなのかソースなのかの引用は、質問者さんご自身しか判別がつかないような物になっています。まずはこの情報が何なのか、ソースであればある程度全容が掴めるものを記載してください。エラーメッセージであれば、その旨記載してエラー全文をコピー＆ペーストしてみてください。

Comment: htmlもhtdocに置いていますか？HTMLやPHPをアクセスしているURLも一緒に教えてください。

Comment: **重複候補** (回答あり): [PHPでデータベースに接続するときにエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70429) / 回答は付いていませんがコードはこちらが同じ: [ブラウザにPHPのコードがそのまま表示されてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70201)

Comment: PCがMACで、直下（サーバールート?）がよくわからななら、MAMPの使用も検討した方が良いと思います。設定からサーバールート場所の確認、変更などが 分りやすいと思います。

Comment: 同じ人の質問かどうかわかりませんが、xamppのドキュメントルートが探せないのであればそういう質問をするべきです。同じ質問を繰り返しても同じ回答が返ってくるだけです。今回の場合はそれを解決するためには、Xamppのドキュメントルート（htdocs）に置くことだけです。

Comment: XAMPPの直下 htdocsに置いても同じ結果です

Comment: URLはlocalhostでアクセスしていますか？

Comment: サーバーホストのことですか？

Comment: localhost:8080です

Comment: file:///Users/user/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/project/hello_world.php

Comment: http://localhost:8080/project/hello_world.php から接続すると表示されるのですが ファルダからドロップするとそのまま表示されます

Comment: htdocsに任意のファイルを置いてurlの最後尾を任意のファイル名に変えても表示されません

Comment: htdocsに置いて、localhostでアクセスすれば正しく表示されていることを理解しているならば問題は「htdocsに任意のファイルを置いてurlの最後尾を任意のファイル名に変えても表示されません」ではないですか？質問を書き換えるか新しく作り直してください。

Comment: わかりました また ここでの追加の質問として ひとつ 挙げておきます URLは 一律 同じところからのアクセス ではないのですか？ HTML PHP 等 でちがうのですか？