# mysqlへのinsert

Tags: php, mysql

何度もためしたのですが

phpからmysqlへの接続ができません

環境はmampです ファイルの置き方がおかしいのでしょうか？

.phpはhtdocsの下です

mysqlはターミナルからダウンロードしてphp接続しなかったらログインできます

php1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>フォーム画面</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>フォーム画面</h1> 
 
<form action="php2.php" method="post">
名前を入力：<input type="text" name="yourname">
<input type="submit" value="登録する">
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

php2.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
 
if(empty($_POST)) {
    header("Location: php1.php");
    exit();
}else{
    //名前入力判定
    if (!isset($_POST['yourname'])  || $_POST['yourname'] === "" ){
        $errors['name'] = "名前が入力されていません。";
    }
}
 
if(count($errors) === 0){
    
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=my;dbname=sample01;charset=utf8';
    $user = 'use';
    $password = 'pass';
 
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO name (name) VALUES (:name)");
    
        if($statement){
            $yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
            //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
            $statement->bindValue(':name', $yourname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
            if(!$statement->execute()){
                $errors['error'] = "登録失敗しました。";
            }
            
            //データベース接続切断
            $dbh = null;    
        }
    
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        $errors['error'] = "データベース接続失敗しました。";
    }
}
 
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>登録画面</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 
<?php if (count($errors) === 0): ?>
<p><?=htmlspecialchars($yourname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."さんで登録いたしました。"?></p>
<?php elseif(count($errors) > 0): ?>
<?php
foreach($errors as $value){
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
 
</body>
</html>
```

エラーは記述どおり

データベース接続失敗しました。

です

mysqlはダウンロードのものとmampのものとあるようですが 適したものはあるのでしょうか

またlocalhost側でもサーバー側でもmysql phpはosのもとでうごいているとおもいますが

phpがmysqlへつなぐのは

サーバー側でもおなじでしょうか

おなじサーバー内でおこっているのでしょうこ

Comment: ご自身が書いたソースコードを提示してください。また接続できませんとは具体的にどういった状況ですか？エラーが出る。真っ白の画面になる等々詳細に追記ください

Comment: 重複候補: [PHPでデータベースに接続するときにエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70429/3060)

Comment: DSN でホスト名が `my` になっていますが、MAMP では `localhost` になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうでした localhost でもだめでした

Comment: 現状では `$errors['error'] = "データベース接続失敗しました。";` とされていますが、`$errors['error'] = $e->getMessage();` に変更して、PDO のエラーメッセージを表示する様にしてみてはどうでしょうか。発生しているエラーの具体的な内容が判るかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Comment: データベースに接続できない場合、大抵は「接続情報 (ホスト名や ID/パスワード) が間違っている」「そもそも接続先の DB が動いていない」などです。MAMP と MySQL 単体の2つあるのもトラブルの元です、状況が把握しやすいようどちらか一方に絞るべきだと思います。

Comment: $errors['error'] = $e->getMessage(); でできました ありがとうございます